# Link between cell area and efflux pump?

Tags: fluorescent-microscopy

I conducted an experiment involving a fluorescent F-actin stain called sir-actin which is removed by an efflux pump. After increased time and removal of the medium containing sir-actin, the cell actively removed the sir-actin using the efflux pump but an increase in cell area was reported when the images were processed in matlab. I was wondering if anyone can propose a possible cause for the increase in cell area with the removal of sir-actin by the efflux pumps. The f-actin of the cytoskeleton was also found to have a reduced length with increased time. Thanks in advance. I also used MSCs and the cells were alive until fixed at each time point and then imaged.

Comment: When you added medium with sir-actin, were you also refreshing growth factors that caused the cells to grow?  Did you compare cells that effluxed your sir-actin with control cells that also received new media for the size you are concerned about?

Comment: @akaDrHouse Yes, growth factors were refreshed and it was compared to a control where the cells were fixed and then stained. All cells were passaged 8 times (P8).

Comment: It wasn't clear from your answer if the control cells also were given fresh media and allowed to incubate for the same amount of time as the sir-acting treated cells. I'm assuming yes.

Comment: @akaDrHouse the control cells were left to incubate for 5h and then fixed then stained and imaged. The test samples were incubated for 5h with sir actin and after the 5h period the sir actin containing medium was replaced with sir-actin free medium and incubated for additional hours (T0, T1, T3, T6) before being fixed and imaged.

Comment: So those controls don't actually mimic the treatment conditions. You may want to have controls that receive the media change again (same as the treated) for the different time points.  However, since you have a T0 time point where the treated cells actually do mimic the controls, does that set of cells still display the difference in cell area compared to controls?